# Is there any quasi-standard for adding "sub-subsections" in a UNIX manual page?

Tags: man

I wonder:
Writing a UNIX manual page using the `man` macro package there is `.SH` (section heading) and `.SS` (subsection).
But what if I want to have "sub-subsections"?

Is there any kind of standard for such?
I think I've seen some page fiddling with the font size (for `troff` at least) in `.SS`, but I'd like to know whether there actually is some (quasi-)standard for such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the short answer is "no"--there is no standard for subsubsections in man pages.

The issue came up last September on [the `linux-man` mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-man/d91100ad-e7b3-a964-797a-fd01eab2765b@gmail.com/), where a large volume of `man` material is curated, and no one there was aware of any accepted idiom for doing this.

The point I would emphasize is this one: "if you need subsubsections in a *man page*, [then] the level of discussion for the page overall is too coarse."  There is no law against breaking up man pages into multiple documents.  groff and Perl do this.

Even [the original `man` macro package's own man page (1979)](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man7/man.7) went out the door without the `SS` subsectioning macro even being documented.

To me this (deliberate?) oversight seems consistent with the original notion of man pages as "terse" documents.

If you had to do it, I would not write my own macro or abuse `TP` as discussed in the `linux-man` thread.  I would probably just use a "run-in heading".  In other words, start a paragraph with a heading title in italics or bold.

```
.P
.B Error handling.
The Z language does not support an exception mechanism.
Therefore you have to check return values at every point blah blah blah
```

Comment: Naturally there are arguments for and against splitting one manual page into several manual pages. Also there is Perl's POD format that allows `=head3` and `=head4` sections. I looked up how those are translated to man commands: They all use `.PP`s around the title and an `.IX Subsection ...`. While `=head3` uses italic font, `=head4` (and the levels below, I suppose) use standard font.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's POD documentation format can be translated to various formats, also to manual pages using `pod2man`.
This is what Perl's `Pod::Man` module does (not claiming that it is some kind of standard):

- `=head1` is translated to `.SH`, using `.IX Header "...."`
- `=head2` is translated to `.SS`, using `.IX Subsection "...."`
- `=head3` is translated to italic font, using `.IX Subsection "...."`
- `=head4` is translated to plain text, using `.IX Subsection "...."`

The title text for `=head3` and `=head4` is surrounded by `.PP`s like this:

```roff
.PP
title text
.IX Subsection "title text"
.PP
```

Comment: I’m not sure the `.IX` usage is particularly significant, that’s just for indexing. Perhaps the common “Subsection” term used for levels 2–4 *is* significant.

Comment: I had been adding the `.IX` mostly for completeness; it has no effect on formatting.